# How can I store a Dynamic generated XML in google Cloud storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I want to first create a XML using JAXB and then save it in Google Cloud Storage. How can I achieve this in JAVA?

Comment: Please give info on what code have u tried,what errors?

Comment: Did you face errors in using JAXB to create XML or interacting with cloud storage using Google API?

Comment: No, there is no issue with the JAXB, Firstly I need to know how to create a new File in GAE as it is giving me  access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "forms.xml" "write") Error. Also I am trying this

Comment: `final FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileInfoKey, formName, new Date(), 0, false, null, clientKey);
            File file = new File("forms.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Forms.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(forms, file);

            InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileService.saveFile(fileInfo, fileInputStream);`

Comment: Please add in the code and errors as part of question,else no one will be able to get a clear picture on this.